# What is the difference?

Tags: usage, word-order, reflexive-pronouns

What is the difference between

> I baked the cake myself

and

> I myself baked the cake

Comment: I think there is no difference between these two sentences. it is just a matter of placing the `direct object` at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: There is a difference in focus, or emphasis, and therefore connotation, between these two constructions. We'd use the latter when we *really* wanted to focus on ourselves, and take pride in having baked the cake *alone*, without help from *anyone else*. By contrast, the former construction puts relatively more focus on the *cake*, and may be underscoring that it's home made (and therefore delicious) or that, eg, you know for sure it doesn't contain poison (in a crime novel, for example).

Comment: @DanBron: sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences mean the same thing, but option 1 sounds more natural to modern English speakers.

This is an example of a reflexive pronoun being used for emphasis. That is, the meaning of the sentence also does not change if the pronoun is removed.

> I baked the cake.

Means the same thing as

> I baked the cake myself.

Adding the reflexive pronoun *myself* adds extra emphasis to the idea that I was the one who baked it. We might picture this sentence being said by a child who just made their first cake or maybe by someone who is very proud of having made such a beautiful cake.

When using a reflexive pronoun for emphasis this way, it is most commonly placed at the end or at least distant from the subject. This is because saying *I myself* is redundant and delays the point of the sentence.

Violating this rule (using *I myself*) can be done to show a high level of formality or to show that the speaker might not be using modern English.

Answer (score -1):

*I baked the cake myself* sounds better.

Also, if you say *I, myself, baked the cake* you need commas around myself.

EDIT: there is no difference in meaning between them.

Comment: I think he has asked the difference `What is the difference? `